# Would Cyanogenmod be faster than stock Android?

Tags: cyanogenmod

I am currently running an HTC One (M8), rooted, stock 5.1 Android Lollipop. If I upgraded to a CM build, would I notice any significant performance increase? Once in a while, 5.1 lags like crap; I don't think they completely fixed the memory leak...so would a CM ROM fix stuff like this? Their latest build for my phone came out yesterday, but it's only a nightly build, all of them are...

So bottom line, should I flash the nightly Cyanogenmod ROM, if I'm looking for stability, speed, and maybe a bit more customization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, rom experience varies device by device (even for same models, it is possible that you may have more/less stable feeling for rom than others).

> so would a CM ROM fix stuff like this?

Yeah there is no memory leak in CM 12.1 right now, that I can assure you.
Stable builds will take a while. Nightly arent bad, I use them too. It really does have a great performance. Never froze in my case, customization is awesome as well.

Now I cannot (and no one can) guarantee same experience for you. I can only give you an idea of what CM 12.1 is now. So->

- Its quite very stable. I cant even remember last time I faced an issue on it. Although RAM is not something I bother about, but CM actually leaves my phone with far better free ram than stock.
- I Dont have HTC ONE M8 so I dont know how the stock rom was. But on my phone, CM is far better than stock.
- I do face some lags. The frequency is somewhere around just 2-5 per day (not more than that definitely, infact I barely notice this).
- You can actually push the performance further. Install a custom kernel, get a better governor (my personal fav is interactive v2). Probably overclock it a little (not needed really, but in case you feel like...). There are a lot of tweaks a kernel can do alone.

> So bottom line, should I flash the nightly Cyanogenmod ROM, if I'm
>   looking for stability, speed, and maybe a bit more customization?

Yes. I cannot say for definite that your experience will be mind blowing and stuff. But CM is one rom you must never judge before you actually try. As I said, even its nightlies are very stable given the amount of time they had to correct bugs. As for customization, it has a great theme manager that allows you to control a lot of aspects separately (different theme for notification panel and statusbar, fonts, bootanimations, icons etc etc), so the customization capabilities are ofcourse far better than stock.

In fact, a lot of roms are ported keeping CM as base. CM is known for its stability and speed (and probably minimalism too if you uninstall those pre-installed bloatware apps. The optimized drivers are another great thing), hence it makes porting roms easier. Definitely worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer, I just flashed a nightly last night (kinda funny), and it was working fine. Some problems I am facing are, when using the trusted face option in the lockscreen, the icon for searching for face and device unlocked aren't updating, it's always a lock symbol so I never know. Also, even after I flashed GApps, I couldn't get some of my favorite games to play. Plus, SwiftKey keeps crashing and keeps me from typing stuff. I really hate doing this because CM actually seemed faster and I loved the themes, but I'm going back to stock for now until a stable is released.. D:

Comment: your welcome :) well, as I said ROM experience varies. I too use cm 12.1 on my Nexus 4 and swiftkey works quite great. On side note, if you like you should also give other ROMs like Blisspop a try. It is a cm based ROM with even more features, stability and improvement. CM will eventually fix these minor bugs in short time anyway. Again, if you are happy with stock, you can of course stay with it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

> So bottom line, should I flash the nightly Cyanogenmod ROM, if I'm looking for stability, speed, and maybe a bit more customization?

Actually, it's not stable because it's "nightly". I think they will never release a stable version right now.

About speed, it's sometimes speed on my Nexus 5 and sometimes lag, I found Stock 5.1 have fast response and good performance than it, and yes it's have a lot of customization and that's the awesome thing in it!

At all, am using multi ROM on my phone and am uses CM as a secondary ROM but I use it all the time, it's not bad! :)